# If $X$ is inductive, then, $U = \{ x \in X \mid x $ is transitive and every nonempty $ z \subset x$ has an $\in$-minimal element $ \}$ is inductive.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is my proof to the following statement correct?

> If $X$ is inductive, then, $U = \{ x \in X \mid x $ is transitive and every nonempty $ z \subset x$ has an $\in$-minimal element $ \}$ is inductive. 
>   ($t$ is an $\in$-minimal element in $z$ if there is no $s \in z$ such that $s \in t$)

Proof: Given $\alpha \in U$ we have to show that $\alpha \cup \{ \alpha \} \in U$. $\beta \in \alpha \cup \{ \alpha \}$ implies $\beta \subset \alpha \cup  \{ \alpha \}$. Take $z \subset \alpha \cup \{ \alpha \}$. If $z \subset \alpha$ then $z$ has an $\in$-minimal element (since $\alpha \in U$). If $z = \alpha$ then $z$ has a minimal element (since $\alpha \in U$).